# Setting parent overflow without breaking position sticky of child

Tags: html, css

I'm using [stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) to stickify one of my columns in a two column design. I need my parent to fill vertically without declaring a height. **stickyfill** detects browsers (firefox, safari) that support *position:sticky;* and lets those browsers take over.

I'm used to simply setting the parent's overflow to hidden but in this case, it breaks *position:sticky;* from working.

My solution is to set the parent's *display* property to *table*. This works from what I've tested, but I'm wondering if this is a bad idea or if there's a **better** way to achieve my goal.

**Example:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jszoukxr/1/)

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 1280px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.right {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Content</div>
    <div class="right">Sticky</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but here are a few couple of things that you should know and/or could improve:

- `overflow:none` is invalid, take a look at the possible values for overflow:

> /* Content is not clipped */
>    **overflow: visible;**
>
> /* Content is clipped, with no scrollbars */ 
>    **overflow: hidden;**
>
> /* Content is clipped, with scrollbars */ 
>    **overflow: scroll;**
>
> /* Let the browser decide */ 
>    **overflow: auto;**
>
> **overflow: inherit;**

- But since you are displaying your parent container as `table`, then `overflow` won't work:

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

- last but not least, if you are using `display:table` in your parent then in your children instead having `floats` use `display:table-cell`

Read [here](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/) info about displaying as tables

#### EDIT:

So from my tests using your fiddle, and as expected, if you want to keep using `display:table`, `overflow`  will be obsolete there, as I explained above.

I tested as well setting `display:inline-table\table-cell\inline-block` and the all worked.

So I don't see disadvantages or advantages to use either one of them.

Comment: @crazymatt you just missed the overflow property :) but stilI really dunno what OP wants

Comment: haha you're right. I just removed the overflow since it the scroll or auto doesnt really work with tables.

Comment: yup you're right only works with block elements, I should add this to my answer :)

Comment: @dippas Whoops, sorry man, was just writing some _psuedo_ markup and forgot the default value is _visible_. :} I've edited my question accordingly...

Comment: @andrgl your CSS still shows `overflow:none`, can you make a fiddle with the polyfill you are using?

Comment: @andrgl edited answer, not sure if this help you, hope it does.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question I am a little unclear on what your overall goal is. But if you are going to set the parent container to `display:table` then you might as well use the `display:table-cell` for the children containers and get rid of the `float`.

```
.wrapper {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    width: 66%;
}
.left {
    width: 44%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Also I dont know what browsers you want to support but the `position:sticky;` [is not support by some major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) and I suggest not using until its better supported.

Comment: Ah sorry, should've mentioned I'm using [stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) which _turns off_ when it detects a browser with position:sticky; support.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `overflow: hidden` is not breaking the sticky behavior, it just sets this parent container to be the scrolling box for the sticky element.

See the [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3 W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos):

> A stickily positioned box is positioned similarly to a relatively
>   positioned box, but the offset is computed with reference to the
>   nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, or the viewport if no ancestor
>   has a scrolling box.

Please see also [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929597/1384441) to a similar question.